# Create React application using password from database of a deleted Wordpress website

Tags: node.js, wordpress, authentication, hash, password-hash

I am in the process of deleting my Wordpress website to replace it with a React application. I have several hundred registered users on my wordpress website and I would like to use these credentials on my React application.

The problem is that in the database I have the user passwords generated by Wordpress and that I cannot decrypt them... My question is: in my React application how can I use the identifiers and password created under Wordpress and stored in my database by deleting my wordpress website? I have already looked at wordpress-hash-node or even md5 but nothing works...

Please help me, I don't know what to do. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Hashed password cannot be unhashed. The easiest thing to do would be to import accounts (emails and so on), generate a temporary password for them and ask them to reset it through an email's campaign.

Comment: You could try using some Javascript code that does the same thing as WordPress's password verification code. Maybe [this](https://github.com/fenying/wp-passhash.js)? To do password verification you give the verifier function both the plain-text password just presented to you by the user and the hashed password from the database, and it says Yes or No.  Then you'll migrate your usernames and the hashed passwords to your new database.

Comment: [@ O. Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205608/o-jones) has given you a correct answer. Before implementing anything I recommend you read this, [Hashing vs Encryption](https://cybernews.com/security/hashing-vs-encryption/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an npm library to verify the password hash from WordPress's `wp_users` table, or from any table containing the `user_login` and `user_pass` column data from that table. This works for me, against `wp_users` on a WordPress 6.1 beta site. So it should be good.

```js
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise'
import PasswordHash from 'wordpress-password-js'

const wordpressHasher = new PasswordHash()

const conn = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'mysql.example.com',
  user: 'databaseuser',
  password: 'redacted',
  database: 'wordpress'
})

const loginFromUser = 'administrator'
const passwordFromUser = 'redacted'

const [rows, _] = await conn.query(
  'SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = ?',
  [loginFromUser])

let userData
for (const row of rows) {
  if (wordpressHasher.check(passwordFromUser, row.user_pass)) {
    userData = row
  }
}
if (userData) {
  console.log('Login Successful', userData)
} else {
  console.error('Login Failure')
}
```

You will, of course, have to do this operation in the back end of your React app.

Don't use that 'wordpress-password-js' package to *create* password hashes. It seems to have far too little randomness in the salt, so the hashes it creates will be too easy to crack. It's fine for validating them.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer, we tested your solution but it still doesn't work... I don't understand, the value returned for the comparison is false, it's crazy !

Comment: If you can give me a couple of user_pass values (password hashes) and the corresponding plain-text unhashed passwords, I'll take a look at it. The code WordPress uses to validate passwords is [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/2bb5679d666474d024352fa53f07344affef7e69/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L2508-L2545) and [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-phpass.php).  The hashing code is described [here](https://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Answer (score 0):

Its good !!!
We adapted the code a bit but it works, thank you again for your help.

Here is the modified code  :

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const PasswordHash = require('wordpress-password-js')

const wordpressHasher = new PasswordHash()

const pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'mysql.example.com',
  user: 'databaseuser',
  password: 'redacted',
  database: 'wordpress'
})
const user_login = "administrator";
const password = 'redacted!';

pool.query('SELECT * from wpv2_users WHERE user_login = ? ', [user_login], function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
      if (results.length > 0) {
        for(const row of results) {
        console.log(wordpressHasher.check(password, row.user_pass));
        }
        if(wordpressHasher.check(password, results.user_pass)){
          userData = results
          console.log(userData)

        }else{  
          console.log('Login Successful',)
        }
    } else {
      console.log('Login Failure')

    }           
});
```